# How long can a flag be active?

Tags: support, flagging

Once a flag has been sent through to the review queue will it ever expire?

I understand that at the time of writing there are 523 items that need review and 45 reviews performed today which means they are being auctioned and everything will be acted on in its own time but still leaves me curious as to age limitation upon review topics. Is there any limitation built into stack exchange that would result in the loss of this items before a reviewer can act on it?

Answer (score 4):

*"It doesn't belong here or is a duplicate"* flags (which are only available as long as you cannot [*vote to close*](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) [aren't sent to the moderator flag queue anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186955/was-this-flag-lost-somehow/187008#187008), but to the *close votes* review queue.

Your close flags will probably be active until the associated, unhandled review entries ([example](https://superuser.com/review/close/140447)) are either accepted or declined by enough reviewers. The queue right now contains over 500 questions, so it might take a while, but there are [several very active reviewers](https://superuser.com/review/close/stats), so it shouldn't stay active indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry I might have been unclear, I'm not asking how long it takes mods to action a flag. I'm asking if a flag were to not receive action from a mod would it expire or remain active till the end of time?

Comment: @50-3 Again, on *these* flags, there's no (diamond) moderator handling them. They generate an entry in the review queue, and as long as these aren't handled, your flag shows up as active. See my edited post.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and sorry for the miss use of the term moderator as I was not sure what to call people who perform review tasks. I've edited my question to reflect a more competent (for lack of a better word) sounding question

Comment: @50-3 Close votes expire. Might be interesting to learn whether close flags expire as well, unfortunately I don't know. Do you think it makes sense for me to delete this answer, now that you changed your question?

Comment: I would keep it as you answered my original question. This lead me to change my phrasing of the question but it still served a vital purpose in this Q & A